# Why is jQuery not recognized in the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [chromedotfiles](https://github.com/diffsky/chromedotfiles) to execute javascript by default on every webpage. The first thing I'd like to do is inject jquery into every webpage so that I can use the console to play with websites on a whim whenever I feel like it. I'm using the following code in my `default.js`:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
setTimeout(function() {$.noConflict();}, 10000);
```

but I always get the 'jQuery isn't defined' error. The strangest part is, I've tried typing `jQuery` into the console *during* the scripted time-out and the console recognizes it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What does the network request tab show? And where is the code that *actually* uses `jQuery`? The `$.noConflict` call (without the 'remove all' parameter) should not overwrite/remove `jQuery`.

Comment: network request tab says 'No requests captured'

The only place jQuery is being used is to call noConflict. The rest is on other websites if i at all( I've tried it on about ten and they all say the same thing).

Comment: If there are 'no requests' then .. the script is not being fetched/loaded (why?).